# How do I make javax marshall return self enclosed tags for empty strings?

Tags: java, xml

I use javax and some XmlAdapters to generate XML. In the adapter I return an empty string as symbol for the presence of the value and null for absence.
The resulting XML looks like:

```
<ex:Example></ex:Example>
```

, which is correct and validates to my XSD (fixed="" minOccurs="0").
What I want is a self enclosed tag like:

```
<ex:Example/>
```

I have only found solutions for the opposite problem.
Is there a way to configure the Marshaller or JAXBContext to output XML to my taste?

Comment: do you use JAXB ? JAXB  does not provide such output

Comment: Yes I do: OutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            this.marshaller.marshal(o, s);
        } catch (JAXBException e) { ... [Marshaller doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html)